# Redefining matrix as product of two different matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have a square matrix $A_{n,n}$, and want to define it as
$$ A = A' A'$$
where the RHS is a product of matrix $A'$ with itself. Is there an analytical way to deduce what $A'$ is, or even if it exists (other than trial and error)? I'm not sure if this is even possible, but am interested to see if there are any methods that exist.

**Edit:** My particular matrix $A$ may not be invertible so what further restrictions, if any, would this place on $A'$?

Comment: What you're after is the [square root of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix, you can find an answer here.